# How to get a range of values from an openoffice calc formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

Am encountered an issue on openOffice Calc.
I need to get a range of values from a formula, that can be used in a dropdownlist/validity.
I have a sheet with following data.

```
      A    B    C
  +---------------
1 |  10    x  
2 |  20    x  
3 |  30    y  
4 |  40    z  
5 |  50    x  
6 |---------------
```

Here I need a list of values of 'A' where values 'B' equals 'x'.
I have checked with LOOKUP/INDEX functions, but it returns a single value(first occurrence) not a range.

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5, SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$5="x",ROW($B$1:$B$5),9^99),ROW())),"")
               ^-------^           ^-------^  ^      ^-------^  ^--^
                   |                   |      |          |       +-> Random big number
                   |                   |      |          +-> Range to check
                   |                   |      +-> Value to check
                   |                   +-> Range to check
                   +-> Range to return
```

You'll need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work, then drag the formula down.

If you start on row 2, you'll have to use `ROW()-1` for it to work. It's generally `ROW()-(k-1)` where `k` is the row number you're using the formula first.

Comment: This works! For OpenOffice :  `**IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5, SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$5="x",ROW($B$1:$B$5),9^99),ROW()))),"")**` .But it will be helpful if I get this range of values for the dropdown list. I mean  the dropdownlist will be having values [10,20,50].

Comment: @CodZilla Hmm, I'm not sure how to do that unfortunately. :( My suggestion would be to have a hidden column for the time being on which the Data Validation pulls its data. If I find something, I'll let you know!

Comment: The hidden column that Jerry recommends is the only thing that worked for me. It's kludgy, but it works.